# MacBook Pro 2017 keyboard and Parrot OS

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad, dual-boot

I'm currently studying and taking courses to be a penetration tester. I've downloaded parrot OS onto a USB drive and done all the necessary requirements to dual boot it onto the Mac.

Once I get it booted, I have the option to choose a username and password.  For some reason, my laptop keyboard doesn't register what I type.

Im using an external mouse because even the trackpad won't work on Parrot.  What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parrot OS does not come with all the drivers necessary to run on a MacBook Pro 2017. You will have to use an external mouse and keyboard to manually install the drivers.

First some extra packages:

```
sudo apt install git kernel-devel dkms
```

Next we need to prepare for the modules to be included in the ramdisk (so they are loaded early during boot):

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/dracut.conf.d/keyboard.conf
# load all drivers needed for the keyboard+touchpad
add_drivers+="applespi intel_lpss_pci spi_pxa2xx_platform apple-ib-tb"
EOF
```

Now get and build the drivers:

```
git clone https://github.com/roadrunner2/macbook12-spi-driver.git
pushd macbook12-spi-driver
git checkout touchbar-driver-hid-driver
sudo ln -s `pwd` /usr/src/applespi-0.1
sudo dkms install applespi/0.1
popd
```

Next we need to set the proper dpi for the touchpad and adjust the sensitivity (download the 61-evdev-local.hwdb, 61-libinput-local.hwdb, and local-overrides.quirks from this gist - the 61-evdev-local.hwdb is only needed for udev < 242, the 61-libinput-local.hwdb is needed for libinput versions < 1.12, the local-overrides.quirks for libinput versions >= 1.12):

```
# if 'udevadm --version' less than 242:
sudo cp ...the-downloaded-61-evdev-local.hwdb... /etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-evdev-local.hwdb
# if 'libinput --version' less than 1.12:
sudo cp ...the-downloaded-61-libinput-local.hwdb... /etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-libinput-local.hwdb
# if 'libinput --version' 1.12 or later:
sudo cp ...the-downloaded-local-overrides.quirks... /etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks
sudo systemd-hwdb update
```

You can test the drivers by loading them and their dependencies:

```
sudo modprobe intel_lpss_pci spi_pxa2xx_platform applespi apple-ib-tb
```

Finally, reboot to make sure it all works correctly:

```
sudo reboot
```

[Link](https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7) for reference and tutorials on installing other drivers (screen brightness control, camera, etc..)

Comment: alright, so when I do this will it have to be from the terminal in Parrot OS or Mac OS?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This needs to be done in ParrotOS. @Tetsujin I will do that now

Answer (score 0):

Would virtualization of the OS suit your needs? Since Parrot OS is Debian based it should be fully supported by Virtualbox.

https://www.virtualbox.org/